# Query to generate map table to matrix table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, matrix, pivot

I have 1 map table

```
Group Task
----- -----
Admin Add
Admin Edit
Admin Delete
Admin View
User  View
```

I need to generate it in a matrix table like

```
Task    Admin   User
------  ------  ------
Add     Yes     No
Edit    Yes     No
Delete  Yes     No
View    Yes     Yes
```

It will help if someone could suggest how SQL Server can generate this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    task,
    max(case when [group] = 'Admin' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) Admin,
    max(case when [group] = 'User'  then 'Yes' else 'No' end) User
from mytable
group by task
```

This works because `'Yes'` > `'No'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you are correct, I updated my answer to return `'No'` as well.